# How to mock ElasticSeach Client

Tags: java, unit-testing, elasticsearch, junit

I am struggling to mock the below code:

```
Client client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
```

**My approach:**

```
Settings.Builder settingsBuilder = mock(Settings.Builder.class);
when(settingsBuilder.put(new String("test"), new String("test"))).thenReturn(settings.settingsBuilder());
when(settingsBuilder.build()).thenReturn(settings);

TransportClient.Builder clientBuilder = mock(TransportClient.Builder.class);
when(clientBuilder.settings(settings)).thenReturn(clientBuilder);
```

Up until this point the test works fine but when trying to mock the other classes used on the client, Mockito throws the following exception:

**Error:**

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
```

**Question:**

Now, I undertand that this could be thrown because I am not mocking something correctly but I can't figure out what is wrong with my mocking this time. How can I mock the client correctly so all dependent classes are mocked and a new mocked client is returned?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess a little bit here, based on your class names.

```
Client client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
```

assuming TransportClient.builder() returns transportClient.Builder, then you need:

```
when(clientBuilder.settings(anyOf(Settings.class)).thenReturn(clientBuilder);
when(clientBuilder.build()).thenReturn(a transport client mock);
```

TransportClient.addTransportAddress, I'm going to assume, doesn't need a mock--it just needs to be verified.

Comment: Hi @Jerry Andrews 

Thanks for your suggestion. It solved the problem but now I am getting the following error:

Wanted but not invoked:
transportClient.addTransportAddress(
    localhost/127.0.0.1:9300
);

I have verified the addTransportAddress, please see below

    verify(mockedTransportClient).addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

Do u know what is causing this problem now? Thanks

Comment: All I can suggest is that you add a captor to addTransportAddress, instead of verifying the inbound precisely, and see how it was actually called (if it was called at all).